# Javascript: Form input audio to audio download link?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, filereader

This is a weird question, but it's been confusing me for a while.

I have this audio input:

```
<input required type="file" id="inputAudio" accept="audio/*" onchange="downloadLink(this);">
```

When you submit some audio, I'd like to add a download link on this element:

```
<a id="blah">Download Audio</a>
```

I've tried doing weird things such as this:

```
function downloadLink(element) {
    var file = element.files[0];
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(e) {
        var data = file.type + ";charset=utf-8," + encodeURIComponent(e.target.result);
        var link = document.getElementById("blah");
        link.href = "data:" + data;
        link.download = "someName." + file.name.split(".").pop();
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
}
```

However, the above causes a download error in Chrome.

Here's a HTML file for testing purposes:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Weird Problem</title>
        <script>
        function downloadLink(element) {
            var file = element.files[0];
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function(e) {
                var data = file.type + ";charset=utf-8," + encodeURIComponent(e.target.result);
                var link = document.getElementById("blah");
                link.href = "data:" + data;
                link.download = "someName." + file.name.split(".").pop();
            };
            reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input required type="file" id="inputAudio" accept="audio/*" onchange="downloadLink(this);">
        <a id="blah">Download Audio</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

EDIT: I just noticed you can embed HTML files:

```js
function downloadLink(element) {
 var file = element.files[0];
 var reader = new FileReader();
 reader.onload = function(e) {
  var data = file.type + ";charset=utf-8," + encodeURIComponent(e.target.result);
  var link = document.getElementById("blah");
  link.href = "data:" + data;
  link.download = "someName." + file.name.split(".").pop();
 };
 reader.readAsDataURL(file);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Weird Problem</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <input required type="file" id="inputAudio" accept="audio/*" onchange="downloadLink(this);">
  <a id="blah">Download Audio</a>
 </body>
</html>
```

Any help would be fantastic!

Comment: you don't need to encode again, the reader already gives you data in base64

Comment: also https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/

Comment: @nullqube even without using encodeURIComponent it gives the same error, download failed. I don't really want to use any external libraries for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the trick is you should just turn it into an **`ObjectURL`** then as the name suggest you can use it as url for `href`,
so now been tested on safari, Chrome, FireFox :

```
var file = element.files[0];
var link = document.getElementById("blah");
link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(file);
link.download = "someName." + file.name.split(".").pop();
```

here it's working at [PlayCode.io](https://playcode.io/60780?tabs=console&app.html&output)

Comment: This version works for MP3 files, but seems to fail for WAV files

Comment: I just test it with .wav file from http://www.music.helsinki.fi/tmt/opetus/uusmedia/esim/index-e.html and worked great.

Comment: what browser are you using? I'm using Chrome and I get a download error every time

Comment: Safari. and yeah you're right It fails at chrome. so let me check